# How can I find my Linksys wifi network from my iPhone

Tags: wifi, iphone

I have a wireless network that I set up using a Linksys WRT54G router. There I can add MAC addresses of client devices that can access my network.

I've added my iPhone's MAC address to this list, but my iPhone doesn't detect my network. What can I do to allow my phone to detect my network?

Comment: If you have MAC filtering turned on, do you also have the BSSID Broadcast turned off (both "security" measures common in home networking)? Have you used your iPhone to connect to other Wi-Fi networks to make sure it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see your network's SSID in the iPhone's list of Wi-Fi networks, you can always try the **Other** option in the Wi-Fi settings screen to manually input the SSID and security settings.

[image: iPhone Wi-Fi settings]

If that doesn't work, you'll probably want to turn on SSID broadcast and temporarily disable your MAC filtering to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have broadcasting of SSID turned on?
If no, turn it on at least until you connect your iPhone to this network.

Turn off MAC address filtering until you connect your iPhone. Then add your iPhone's MAC address to the list (from the list of connected devices) and turn filtering back on.
This way you will be sure you did not misspelled your MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

There is also getting very close to your router/base station (this is a real tip) ... and I find that Forget This Network has to be run, otherwise the iPhone hangs onto the 169.xxx.xxx address forever and the user doesn't know it ...

I hope, as well, you are using Airport Utility. Try setting up a Guest or open network first and see if you can't automatically join that. Subsequently changing its settings to your password network works.